How to parse the current JSON_OBJECT into a list form
I'm having a hard time trying to understand how can I switch results within my query.
I have the following piece that runs into an Oracle database:
TO_NCLOB(JSON_OBJECT(
            'name' VALUE TRIM(tb1.DS_NAME),
            'birth' VALUE tb2.DT_BIRTH,
            'id' VALUE TRIM(tb2.P_ID),
            'email' VALUE tb3.DS_EMAIL,
            'phone' VALUE tb3.NUM_PHONE,
            'add' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(TRIM(tb4.ADD))
                FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_4 tb4
                INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE_5 tb5
                    ON tb6.ID = tb5.ID
                WHERE tb4.ID_F = tb5.ID_F),
            'formula' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(TRIM(tb4.FORM))
                FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_4 tb4
                INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE_5 tb5
                    ON tb6.ID = tb6.ID_U
                WHERE tb4.ID_FORM = tb5.ID_FORM),
            'code' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(TRIM(tb7.CODE))
                FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_4 tb4
                INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE_5 tb5
                    ON tb6.ID = tb5.ID_U
                INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE_8 tb8
                    ON tb5.ID_E = tb8.ID_E
                INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE_7 tb7
                    ON tb8.ID_UN = tb7.ID_P))) AS USER_INFO

I need to transform the current output which is something like this:
{
    "name": "JOSEPH STANLY",
    "id": "5821451552112234",
    "email": "jsstently@gmail.com",
    "phone": "3585445551451155",
    "birth": "1980-01-29",
    "add": [
        "255521",
        "357441"
    ],
    "formula": [
        "Architect",
        "Interior Designer"
    ],
    "code": [
        "8955445",
        "1225587"
    ]
}

Into something like this:
[
    {
        "name": "JOSEPH STANLY",
        "id": "5821451552112234",
        "email": "jsstently@gmail.com",
        "phone": "3585445551451155",
        "birth": "1980-01-29",
        "add": "223505",
        "formula": "Architect",
        "code": "8955445",
    },
    {
        "name": "JOSEPH STANLY",
        "id": "5821451552112234",
        "email": "jsstently@gmail.com",
        "phone": "3585445551451155",
        "birth": "1980-01-29",
        "add": "1980-01-29",
        "formula": "Interior Designer",
        "code": "1225587",
    }
]

As you can see, some of the fields that compose the field USER_INFO have multiple information. How can I split like the example above?
I tried removing the JSON_ARRAYAGG within the SELECT, but that didn't work.

If you post the actual code you tried, and explain what you mean by "didn't work", someone may be able to help fix it.

Why does the second object have no birth field, but the expected birth value in the add field?

there is, I misplaced it. I fixed it.

Can you share some CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to populate the data that you are currently working with? It will make it much easier for others to help you.

with data(js) as (
    select q'~{
    "name": "JOSEPH STANLY",
    "id": "5821451552112234",
    "email": "jsstently@gmail.com",
    "phone": "3585445551451155",
    "birth": "1980-01-29",
    "add": [
        "255521",
        "357441"
    ],
    "formula": [
        "Architect",
        "Interior Designer"
    ],
    "code": [
        "8955445",
        "1225587"
    ]
}~'
)
select 
json_arrayagg(
    json_object(
     ta.name, ta.id, ta.email, ta.phone, ta.birth,
     "add", formula, code
     )
    )
from 
data d,
json_table(
    js,
    '$'
    columns (
        name path '$.name',
        id path '$.id',
        email path '$.email',
        phone path '$.phone',
        birth path '$.birth',
        nested path '$.add[*]'
        columns (
            idx for ordinality,
            "add" path '$'
        )
    )
) ta
left join 
json_table(
    js,
    '$'
    columns (
        id path '$.id',
        nested path '$.formula[*]'
        columns (
            idx for ordinality,
            formula path '$'
        )
    )
) tf on ta.id = tf.id and ta.idx = tf.idx
left join json_table(
    js,
    '$'
    columns (
        id path '$.id',
        nested path '$.code[*]'
        columns (
            idx for ordinality,
            code path '$'
        )
    )
) tc on ta.id = tc.id and ta.idx = tc.idx
;




   [
{"name":"JOSEPH STANLY","id":"5821451552112234","email":"jsstently@gmail.com","phone":"3585445551451155","birth":"1980-01-29","add":"255521","formula":"Architect","code":"8955445"},
{"name":"JOSEPH STANLY","id":"5821451552112234","email":"jsstently@gmail.com","phone":"3585445551451155","birth":"1980-01-29","add":"357441","formula":"Interior Designer","code":"1225587"}
]

